# Error: Wheels are not supported

Tags: python, django, travis-ci

The travis test returns an error which states `Error: Wheels are not supported` when it is install Django==2.0.4 even though the Django version supports wheels.

What is the problem here?

Relevant Link : 
https://github.com/django-blog-zinnia/zinnia-wysiwyg-tinymce/pull/10

Answer (score 0):

It might be the problem with the package`setuptools`. Try to use below version in your `travis.yml`

```
setuptools==38.2.4
```

Comment: It broke again.